# Get previous set values of php array

Tags: php

I have a method which creates an array of ten elements in php.

```
array(
    key  => value,
    key2 => value2,
    key3 => value3,
    ...
)
```

After array is created (In a class via a method), half of the array elements (1 to 5) will be shown on page load and the remaining elements will be shown via AJAX one by one. How can I achive this in php?

Array is populated from `random` MySQL results.

Comment: So what is your question? Like how to show all elements one by one via AJAX?

Comment: Are you trying to paginate the elements if that's what you mean ? 
or are you trying to do some visual effect ?
can you explain a bit further what you're trying to do?

Comment: For ex a method will create an array with ten elements 1 to 10. When index.php is loaded 1 ... to 5 elemets will be shown then an ajax call will be thrown which will display element of index 6, then after another ajax call the element of index 7 will be shown ... and so for the remaining elements. @Rizier123

Comment: Once the request is fulfilled and sent back to the user, the rest of your array elements are dropped from memory as php has completed its task. You'll need some javascript to keep track of what you want to display next and go back to the server to fetch the ones you want afterward.

Comment: 5 images are shown on page load then with an setInterval  on JS an ajax call is made which will display the six-th image and replace the first, then the 7-th will replace the second and so on. @MostafaTorbjørnBerg

Comment: Do you necessarily need Ajax to do this? You can assign your array to a JavaScript array and then just access the array as you please with your button/link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.

Once the original request is fulfilled, if you've only shown 5, the rest are not natively held in memory for you to just go back and get.

You'll need a bit of javascript or something to hold on to whatever the next index is, and go fetch it from the server.

You could, for example, hand the last index array off to javascript and then have it return to the server just to fetch one item.

You'll of course need to write some php to handle the ability to just fetch 1 item at a time specifically but that's on you.

---

Or, you drop all the images onto the page and just use javascript to hide and show the ones you want.

---

Your question also might be closed as "too broad" as there are a whole bunch of ways to accomplish what it sounds like you're trying to do and this sort of thing can be googled and answered fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the last key you have shown via AJAX and get the others that come after passed key.
For example if you have shown the results 
'key', 'key2', ... , 'key5'
then pass the number 5 via AJAX and get the next item
'key' . 5 + 1 that is 'key6'
then pass the number 6 and get the next item
'key' . 6 + 1 that is 'key7'

Comment: Array is populated from `random` MySQL results.